# Drag'n'drop outlook mail to wf is working incorrectly

Tags: winforms, drag-and-drop, outlook, office-interop

I have WF application that allows to drag and drop emails from outlook and read the contents of an email. But when I drag'n'drop email, the emails that were dropped before are not cleared up and as a result I get the copies of the previous emails + current dragged email.

Example:

- Drop mail_1 - OK
- Drop mail_2 - drops mail_1 and mail_2
- Drop mail_3 - drops mail_1, mail_2 and mail_3

  ```
    private void listBox1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
          {
              Explorer oExplorer = _Outlook.ActiveExplorer();
              Selection oSelection = oExplorer.Selection;
              foreach (object item in oSelection)
              {
                  MailItem mi = (MailItem)item;
                  StringBuilder mailHeader = new StringBuilder();
                  mailHeader.Append(count + ". "+mi.SenderName +" | " + mi.Subject);
                  mailList.Items.Add(mailHeader.ToString());
                  count++;
                  oExplorer.RemoveFromSelection(item); //unfortunatelly this not clearing previous emails.

              }
              //oExplorer.ClearSelection() is not clearing either
          }
  ```

How can I set the application, that only selected items are dragged into the WF? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Drag event handler add the following line of code:

```
 e.Data.GetData(“RenPrivateMessages”);
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate more, why is this working? Or some source where I can read on this topic. thanks!